# Align Polyline to Edge of Road in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I saw this in the web [image]
So I confirmed that it is possible to have 2 fill in 2 different polylines in one path in Google Maps.

To experiment this, I tried to add only one polyline at first using this code:

```
public static void drawEncodedPolyOnMap(String encoded, GoogleMap map) {
    List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
            (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        points.add(p);
    }

    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(7).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true).addAll(points));
}
```

But it is not giving me the display that I expected

[image]

Basically in my case, polylines get center-aligned even though the markers are at the edge of the road, the case I don't like to happen.

Is it possible to align the polyline with the markers in Android? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems no one is answering and I just found out a way on how to do it.

Basically, I just updated my drawEncodedPolyOnMap to add paddings to the original `LatLng` returned by the `bit shifting`. So here goes the code below

```
public static void drawEncodedPolyOnMap(String encoded, GoogleMap map, boolean type) {
    List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        double newLat = (((double) lat / 1E5));
        double newLng = (((double) lng / 1E5));

        if(type){
            points.add(new LatLng(newLat+PADDING_LAT, newLng+PADDING_LNG));
        }else{
            points.add(new LatLng(newLat-PADDING_LAT, newLng-PADDING_LNG));
        }
    }

    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().width(7).color((type)?Color.RED:Color.GREEN).geodesic(true).addAll(points));
}
```

And that's it. Problem solved.